# Add icon to explorer icon dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How do I add icon resource to `Change Icon...` dialog from `.lnk` properties in Visual Studio 2015?
Like on picture
[image: Choose icon dialog]
I'm planning to use them in `regedit` for file extension icon like `MyApp.exe,2`

Comment: Excuse me? No one knows how to do it?